# Does the perceived curvature of the earth's horizon subjectively underestimate the vastness of earth's actual curvature?

Tags: optics, curvature, earth, perception

When one is standing on a beach and looks out onto the horizon, including peripherally and/or turning one's head from side to side, the horizon certainly appears curved to me. And yet the sheer size of the earth in relation to us might suggest the horizon would appear flatter to us than it subjectively does. I wonder if what I consider to be the definite perceived curvature of the horizon is an "illusion" created by the wrapping of the image around our curved eye anatomy / optical receptors, with respect to the fact we should be seeing a subjectively flatter horizon based on the earth's enormous circumference in relation to us. Or perhaps it is an "illusion" created by other perspective characteristics, such as that a flatter-perceived horizon would go on indefinitely, which would be visually, cognitively and/or geometrically difficult to terminate or comprehend -- in any case, it's hard to imagine. Another notion that somehow the horizon wraps around our space-time, I surmise is not a viable explanation in practical terms, since my layman’s instincts lead me to think that our optics function mostly within Newtonian physics and Euclidian geometry, although I have heard one opinion that things get smaller in the distance because they lie further back in time. I'm guessing "illusion" may be a distinct possibility when it comes to the perceived curvature of the horizon, because if the perceived curvature of the horizon indeed corresponded to the grand curvature of the earth, my hunch is that the earth would then be remarkably small compared to what it really is.

Comment: I feel this is not opinion based (the stated close reason) and should be reopened.  It's an everyday physics experience.  I can't find a duplicate so I think it explores a common question and is not really "subjective" except in the sense described by @claudio-saspinkski.

Answer (score 1):

If we are on a beach, and our eyes at 3m above the sea level, the horizon is a circle of about 6km. It seems consistent with our intuition.

$r_h = \sqrt{R_e^2 - h^2} = \sqrt{6371^2 - 0,003^2} = 6,2km$

Comment: Thanks to both commenter and answer provider. I'll study the equation for now.

Comment: On Wikipedia's horizon page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon under subheading "Appearance and Usage," it states, when discussing practices of perspective drawing: "... For observers near sea level, the difference between this geometrical horizon (which assumes a perfectly flat, infinite ground plane) and the true horizon (which assumes a spherical Earth surface) is imperceptible to the unaided eye." If the earth's curvature is imperceptible, what may the perceived curvature in real life situations be attributed to? (Or does that only refer to the practical aspects of perspective drawing?)

Comment: Upon standing on the beach recently once more, crouching down right near the water, I am somewhat more open to the idea that the horizon indeed appears as a straight line, as stated in Wikipedia, noted above. The waves interfere a bit with an unobstructed view of the ocean's horizon at zero elevation. I find that the question of whether one is looking at a circle from the side -- as a line -- instead of the contour of a sphere, which should appear convex, is still something to contemplate.